# Kubernetes - kubectl or istioctl list all internal dns

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In Kubernetes(kubectl) 1.10 or Istio(istioctl) 1.0

I know I can list services with `kubectl get svc`, and I can figure out the namespace and from there add `.svc.cluster.local`.

Is it possible to list internal dns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you would have to list the DNS of each pod manually as there is no command available for both Istio or Kubernetes. You can however look at this following [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) which will guide you into creating a shell in the running container so that you can list the internal DNS manually